# Using the MVP pattern

Tags: java, gwt, mvp, gwt-platform

I have this web application which I have made with MVC pattern, however I am trying to adapt the MVP pattern.

I am using the GWTPlatform library which I have migrated some of the codes already, mainly to the `Presenter` and the `View`. However I have not seen any comprehensive material to explain how to actually deal with the `Model` part. In my MVC pattern I have the model in the controller (in MVC) and the Views listen to changes in the Model to update the views. The model is updated by the controller, e.g `fireUpdateUser()` function is fired as a result of opening the "user page" for example which then updates the model.

How to I actually deal with the model in MVP if I already have remote services RPC (e.g UserService, UserServiceImpl); With Gwtplatform, I can just put a RPC call in the onReset() function of a presenter then essentially do a `getView().getSomething().setValue(something)` to update the View associated. In this case I did not have to use any model at all? Also, what are the purposes of EventHandler and Activities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your services you can inject `DAO` objects that deal with your data (model). You usually have an interface and its implementation.

```
public interface IMyDao {
    List<String> getAllObject();
}

public class MyDao implements IMyDao {
    public List<String> getAllObject() {
        List<String> os = new ArrayList<String>();
        // DB access or Datastore (Sample code)
        os = datastore.query(...);
        return os;
    }
}
```

and in your service

```
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

  private final MyDao dao;

  @Inject
  public ServiceImpl(final MyDao dao) {
    this.dao = dao;
  }

  public List<String> getAllObject() {
    // Some processing
    return dao.getAllObject();
  }
}
```

Your service will be called by the presenter. So the workflow is  Presenter -> Dao (Model) -> View (updated by the presenter).

Have a look at that [ebook](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-gae-book/), it will give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read this articles, they describe the basic concepts GWTPlatform, and examples of using it:

- [GWTPlatform Getting Started](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStarted)
- [Other getting Started](http://uptick.com.au/content/getting-started-gwt-platform)
- [Blog about GWTP](http://arcbees.wordpress.com/category/development/gwt-platform/)