# Model-View-Controller for GWT

Tags: model-view-controller, gwt

I know that most GWT based application now is being implemented using the MVP pattern, however I still want to know which MVC framework is the most mature and can be used for production-grade web application built with GWT.

Searching the web I can't seem to find a MVC framework anything comparable to Mvp4gwt and GwtPlatform in the MVP frameworks, in terms of user base and activities in the code.

Comment: ...a MVC framework that is still active today

Comment: As an experienced GWT developer, I'm telling you that you really want to use MVP. Don't be lazy -- learn the correct pattern.

Comment: @TravisWebb I'm not being lazy, I have used MVP and have my web app used MVP (at least for the most part)

Comment: I reiterate: do not use MVC for a GWT app. There is a reason no one is answering this question. I have tried it, and it's extremely painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must shoot yourself in the foot, these are the only two MVC frameworks for GWT that I've heard of:

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mvc/

http://code.google.com/p/gwittir/

Neither of these have had a release in over two years. Probably due to lack of community interest, and because MVP is better in every conceivable way. Using MVC with GWT is like installing square tires on a Ferrari.

Comment: I just wonder why Spring still have "Spring MVC", anyway since you really advise to use MVP pattern, perhaps you can suggest something from my MVP question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155289/using-the-mvp-pattern

Answer (score 1):

You could use JetPad-Mappers, a minimalistic MVC framework developed at JetBrains and used in several (currently unreleased) products.

- https://github.com/JetBrains/jetpad-mapper

Disclaimer, I am involved in development of this framework.

Comment: Looks like a very interesting project. How's the progress?

Comment: Cool, I am able to build it

Comment: @xybrek We use it for several projects for several years.

Comment: I see, I'm using MVP pattern now, however I will like to see your MVC framework in action